# Rails: In-place editing is a thing but what about in-place creating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I know [in-place editing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wes6OBHGNoc) is a thing. But how do I go about in place creating.

I have `items` associated to a category. If I want a page to display all the items in category x, and have the user be able to add a new item to the category from the category page with the list of items in the category updating to show the new item added all without the page doing a full refresh how would I go about doing this?

Is there a gem for this type of thing?

Comment: i think adding data with ajax would do your job.

Comment: Yea ajax would be my go to if there isn't a gem or other known method.

Comment: The solution is AJAX calls. you have to use javascript to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the gem is called [`Cocoon`](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) (if you have [nested fields](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)).

--

It would work (manually) *like* this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :categories, only: [:new, :destroy] #-> url.com/posts/:post_id/categories
end

#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @post = Post.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html, only: :new

   def new
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @post.categories.build
   end

   def destroy
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @category = Category.find params[:id]

      @post.categories.delete @category
   end
end

#app/views/categories/new.js.erb
$category = $("<%=j render "form", locals: { post: @post } %>");
$($category.html()).appendTo(".categories");

#app/views/categories/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for post do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :categories, child_index: Time.now.to_i do |category| %>
      <%= category.text_field :x %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

#app/views/categories/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post, remote: true do |f| %>
   <div class="categories">
       <%= f.fields_for :categories do |category| %>
           <%= category.text_field :x %>
       <% end %>
   </div>
   <%= link_to post_new_categories_path(@post), remote: true %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will append new items to your `posts#show` view via ajax. It should work, although may need tweaking a little.

Comment: Looks pretty good I'll give it a shot and see if it does the job

Comment: Doesn't look like it will work. I need 2 separate forms. 1. for saving the category and another to easily add new items. this does it all in one form submit